# how to check if two timestamps are in range of allowable error

Tags: python

I want to compare two timestamps and see if there are in 3 seconds. The first format will be like `13:15:19.654` and the second will be like `1:15:20 PM`. How can I implement?

For example:

> `13:15:19.654` and `1:15:20 PM` return True
>
> `13:15:19.654` and `1:15:25 PM` return False

Note, both timestamps are string from different file.
Here is my code:

```
deviation = 3
timestamp_a = '13:15:19.654'
timestamp_b = '1:15:25 PM'

hour_a = timestamp_a.split(':')[0]
hour_b = timestamp_b.split(':')[0]
if 'PM' in timestamp_b:
  hour_b = str(int(hour_b) + 12)

minute_a = timestamp_a.split(':')[1]
minute_b = timestamp_b.split(':')[1]

second_a = timestamp_a.split(':')[2].split('.')[0]
second_b = timestamp_b.split(':')[2].split()[0]

time_a = int(hour_a) * 3600 + int(minute_a) * 60 + int(second_a)
time_b = int(hour_b) * 3600 + int(minute_b) * 60 + int(second_b)

return abs(time_a - time_b) < deviation
```

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: Are your values in `string` or `datetime`?

Comment: @komatiraju032 I've updated code. thank you.

Comment: @CodePope Their type are string. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert them to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and then compute the difference:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp_a = '13:15:19.654'
timestamp_b = '1:15:25 PM'

first_datetime = datetime.strptime(timestamp_a, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
second_datetime = datetime.strptime(timestamp_b, "%I:%M:%S %p")
if abs((first_datetime-second_datetime).total_seconds()) < 3:
  print('Diff less than 3')
  # do something
else:
  print('Diff not less than 3')
  # do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert string to datetime object and work from there:

```py
import datetime

time_a = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:15:19.654', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
time_b = datetime.datetime.strptime('1:15:20 PM', '%I:%M:%S %p')

delta = time_a - time_b

time_diff = abs(delta.total_seconds())
print('Difference in seconds: ', time_diff)

threshold = 3.0
if time_diff <= threshold:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Difference in seconds:  0.346
True
```

For more datetime format directives [check here](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime)